# nodemailer multiple recipients different context

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, email, nodemailer

I am trying to implement a method to send emails to multiple recipients but also I want to pass to the html template the user attribute which will have the name of the recipient. (I AM USING NODEMAILER as a nodejs module)

My code in this stage is like this:

```
SellerMatched: function (fromUser, offer, cb) {

        var maillist  = [];
        var users = [];

        for (var i=0; i<fromUser.length; i++)
        {
            maillist[i]=fromUser[i].email;
            users[i] = fromUser[i].Name;
        }


        maillist.toString();
        users.toString();



        mail.sendMail({
            from: 'Website Support <help@domain.com>',
            to: maillist,
            subject: 'Seller Matched',
            template: 'SellerMatch',
            context: {
                user: users,
                username: offer.owner.username,
                OfferName: offer.name,
                category: offer.category
            }
        }, cb);
    }
```

and the html have those attributes: It's something like this:

```
...

Hi {{user}},

A offer is uploaded that matched your preference. 
Offer detail:
Name : {{OfferName}}
By: {{username}}
Category: {{category}} 

....
```

This is working properly, emails are sent to the recipients but in the attribute Hi {{user}}, I want to show only the name of recipient because now it shows the array of all recipients.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I saw in https://hashnode.com/post/nodemailer-multiple-recipients-different-context-ciret279f03hduy539u4tolck

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fromUser.length; i++) {
    promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        mail.sendMail({
            from: 'Website Support <help@domain.com>',
            to: fromUser[i].email,
            subject: 'Seller Matched',
            template: 'SellerMatch',
            context: {
                user: fromUser[i].Name,
                username: offer.owner.username,
                OfferName: offer.name,
                category: offer.category
            }
        }, function(err, info) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(info)
            }
        });
    }));`enter code here`
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function(infos) { cb(null, infos) }, function(err) { cb(err) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are sending **one** Email to a list of recipients. I guess what you want to do is send one Email to **each** recipient in the list so you can set the greeting per recipient.

```
SellerMatched: function (fromUser, offer, cb) {

    for (var i=0; i<fromUser.length; i++)
    {
        mail.sendMail({
            from: 'Website Support <help@domain.com>',
            to: fromUser[i].email,
            subject: 'Seller Matched',
            template: 'SellerMatch',
            context: {
                user: fromUser[i].Name,
                username: offer.owner.username,
                OfferName: offer.name,
                category: offer.category
            }
        }, cb);
    }
}
```